# Will this mark [0] be any number or the first integer?

Tags: java

So the question was to ask to find the highest and lowest mark in an array. This is part of the program.

```
 int [] mark = {70,75,56,82,20};
 int high = mark[0];
 int low = mark[0];
```

So in here low and high was alr putted in mark [0] which was 70 I believe.

Can we do it like this instead so that it can search?
    Int high = mark [];
     Int low = mark [];

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: What is `Int` ?

Comment: Java programming

Comment: Too bad I cant place a picture

Comment: This teacher of mine cant teach well and often makes mistake, now I doubt every answer given by him is right

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but if I guess the question correctly, if you want to leave the initial values empty you do just `Int high; Int low;`, but I assume the algorithm requires for there to be an initial value.

Comment: can you please frame the question again in much simpler and specific manner!

Answer (score 0):

It was the *first* part of finding high and low. The entire picture is:

```
int [] mark = {70,75,56,82,20};
int high = mark[0];
int low = mark[0];
for (int i = 1; i < mark.length; ++i) {
    if (mark[i] > high) {
        high = mark[i];
    }
    if (mark[i] < low) {
        low = mark[i];
    }
}
```

That is searching upwards from the second (`[1]`) mark.